# What is the best way to cut and paste a column with a defined name to a new worksheet, and why doesn't my code work?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to efficiently copy columns of data from one worksheet to a second worksheet in Excel using VBA, starting with a defined name for the column.

I am unsure why my code doesn't work.  I cannot emphasis enough, how little I know about coding.  I am attempting to teach myself VBA in order to manipulate vast quantities of data in Excel.

```
Function SortDataC()

'cuts and pastes columns from the unsorted worksheet to the sorted worksheet

Worksheets("UnsortedData").Range("DeltaModScore").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("SortedData").Columns(1)

End Function
```

DeltaModScore is the column header.  If I look in defined named it is present on the sheet UnsortedData with workbook scope.  Thus, I assume I have screwed up the syntax somewhere?

I have used the term Sheets("UnsortedData").Range..... as well as Worksheets.... as you see above. I've been basically searching the web for code examples and trying to get them to work with my data.  Inevitably, I end up with errors I have much difficulty fixing.  I hope this is something simple someone can point out.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Change `Columns(1)` to `Columns(1).Cells(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You only require the single top left cell of a destination to complete a Copy & Paste.

```
SUB SortDataC()

   'COPIES and pastes columns from the unsorted worksheet to the sorted worksheet

    Worksheets("UnsortedData").Range("DeltaModScore").Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets("SortedData").Cells(1, "A")

End SUB
```

Functions are intended to return a value. If you simply want to complete an operation, a sub procedure is more appropriate.